# Who do I ask about unfair downvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with unexplained downvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29020/what-to-do-with-unexplained-downvotes)

I have a [legit question](https://serverfault.com/questions/99857/installing-a-ruby-app-as-a-linux-service) on serverfault.com.  There were several good answers and no complaints.  Then, I notice I have a score of -1 on the question.  No explanation.  How can I report this?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me, so I've +1ed it. You're now up a net of 10 points (since the normal -2 didn't affect you because you only had 1 rep). Exciting times.

Comment: Thank you.  I gave you a point too :)

Answer (score 8):

You can't. Votes are individual expression, and people are free to vote however they wish. That being said, you can ask as a comment on your question (which I see you did).

Comment: Perhaps, when all this was conceived, it was thought that the 2 rep point penalty to the *downvoter* would be a slight disincentive. But as rep scores get higher and higher, it's probably no disincentive at all.

Comment: +1 I agree. Downvoting a question isn't something that merits reporting, and people don't have to justify their votes either way if they don't want to.

Comment: @pavium - I think you mean 1 rep point penalty to the downvoter.

Comment: @Dominic, thanks, I was confusing the downvoter and downvoted.

Comment: The problem with NOT having anonymous voting is that it would result in retaliatory voting patterns, which would make the site completely worthless.

Comment: Well I believe I am being harassed/stalked...and downvoted. I can think of less pleasant ways of dealing with this ... I am going to give the people who handle posts that are flagged another chance to stop the harassment....